# Call one python script from inside the other script

Tags: python

I have 2 python scripts, First script runs like this on Windows:

```
%python script1 -d dir1
```

Second script runs like this:

```
%python script2 -d dir1. Both are working fine. Instead of running both sequentially I want that script1 at the end call script2.
```

Note: in script1 I parse dir1 as sys.argv[2]
I used like this at the end of the script1 :

```
os.system("c:\ipython\ipython\ipy.exe script2 -d sys.argv[2]")
```

It failed because treated sys.argv[2] literally
When I replaced sys.argv[2] for hard-coded dir1 it worked correctly.
The error I've got:

```
WindowsError: [Errno 2] [Errno 3] Could not find a part of the path 'N:\Scripts\deleteMe\sys.argv[2]'
```

My 2 questions:

1. How could I fix it?
2. How could I replace hard-coded path to 'ipython' to something more appropriate?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [subprocess.Popen](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCcQFjAA&url=http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html&ei=xxkuU52rF4KDogT2w4DoCA&usg=AFQjCNFdC9kYg-WOjimGNxIC3jQDKuai7A&sig2=hVwisSVJzI83rLnMSSOIjQ&bvm=bv.62922401,d.cGU):

```
subprocess.Popen(['python', 'script2', '-d', sys.argv[2]])
```